# A star Pathfinding algorithm with Lego Mindstorms ev3

Tags: a-star, lego-mindstorms-ev3

Trying to have a path finding algorithm within Lego mindstorms. I was hoping to find a way to implement A* Into the Ev3 so that it can map the maze and find a solution. I am coding in the discontinued version of Mindstorms with the block based programing.

I have tried to have it map out intersections as nodes, but it doesn't seem to work in the overall aspect. Any suguestions are welcome.